# Best way to get records from another model again and again - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Booking` which contains `space_id` attributes associated with `Space` Model by `belongs_to :space`.

Now I have multiple spaces and want to count each booking with respect to every id.

I want to get the best way to fatch records from DB without fire query again and again.
Currently, I'm doing like this:

```
spaces = Space.all
result = []
spaces.each do |s|
    result << s.as_json.merge(:bookings_counts=>s.bookings.count)
end
```

but this is firing query again and again form db. is there any best way to do  this?

Answer (score 1):

This is called an "N+1 queries" problem. In Rails you can use eager loading to resolve it. You could use `includes` to load records in a single query by changing the first line of your code to

```
spaces = Space.eager_load(:bookings)
```

Here is a good explanation and comparison of ways (`includes`, `eager_load` and `preload`) to do eager loading in Rails [link](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/).